# TLS v1.2 support on Webview Android

Tags: android, ssl, webview, tls1.2

I faced with one big problem: built-in browser (WebView), what we use for authentication, supports TLS 1.1+ only from 4.4 KitKat. Android OS supports TLS 1.1+ from 16 API version, but WebView supports TLS 1.1+ only from 19 API version. I didn’t find opportunity to set TLS protocol to WebView manually. So we can’t login in system through web on devices below KItKat. I checked this on real devices Samsung 4.1.2 and Asus 4.2.2 , and emulator 4.3.1

Comment: And your question is .... ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved this by manually setting the TLS protocol version in my android app.

Comment: hi could you please tell me how to set menually TLS protocol to my app

Comment: While creating the socket. Call socket.enableProtocols(String ["TLS 1.0","TLS 1.1"]). It will enable the passed protocols for your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,but in webView its not loading the url of salesforce , so is there any way to load url with TLS enabling in webview.

Comment: Which TLS version salesforce url is using? It will depend on your device Android version and TLS version. TLS 1.2 is supported only after kitkat

Comment: Android 4.1 Jellybean also supports TLS 1.2 @SandeepAgrawal. The question is, is there a way to enable for the Webview